# select code as ParentID if not null

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have got the table named Users.
There are columns: Id, code, ParentID.
ParentID is the pointer to ID column, and can be null.
For example:

```
ID Code  ParentId
1 Poland null
2 Germany 1
```

I would like to get the following result.
ParentId as code if not null and Id as code.

Example(accordong to above example):

```
ParentId Id
null, poland
Germany, Poland
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a self join... and Poland is the Parent of Germany, not the other way around according to your example. Thus, your expected results are wrong.

```
declare @table table (ID int, Code varchar(64), ParentId int)
insert into @table
values
(1,'Poland',null),
(2,'Germany',1)

select
    ParentId = t2.Code
    ,ID = t.Code
from
    @table t
    left join
    @table t2 on
    t2.ID = t.ParentId
```